# Can I customize the format of Emacs' buffers-menu?

Tags: emacs

The Emacs buffers menu shows two columns: One with the buffer name, and one with the filename, with full path. The paths in our projects can become very long, spanning more than one screen. So I would like to not show them in the buffers menu. How can I achieve this? Bonus: use a tooltip for the path instead.

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question (hence a comment) but have you looked at [Ibuffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode)?

Comment: No, I did not know lbuffer so far. I also just found [buffer-menu+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferMenuPlus#BufferMenu%2b), which can en- and disable the columns displayed in the menu.

Comment: Cool, why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: I think it is not the right choice. It seems there is buffer-menu (that's just a buffer displaying a buffer list), buffers-menu (that's the one you get with Ctrl+Left Mouse Button), buffer-menu+ (that's a better buffer displaying a buffer list), and your lbuffer (that's again a buffer displaying a buffer list). And then there is msb-mode, which I haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Emacs comes with sources, I just took the liberty to adjust the mouse-buffer-menu. I put this in my `init.el` to override the default implementation that creates the `mouse-buffer-menu-alist`. This one does away with the filename and only shows the buffer name. For my needs this is enough:

```
(defun mouse-buffer-menu-alist (buffers)
  (let (tail
    (maxlen 0)
    head)
    (setq buffers
      (sort buffers
        (function (lambda (elt1 elt2)
                (string< (buffer-name elt1) (buffer-name elt2))))))
    (setq tail buffers)
    (while tail
      (or (eq ?\s (aref (buffer-name (car tail)) 0))
      (setq maxlen
        (max maxlen
             (length (buffer-name (car tail))))))
      (setq tail (cdr tail)))
    (setq tail buffers)
    (while tail
      (let ((elt (car tail)))
    (if (/= (aref (buffer-name elt) 0) ?\s)
        (setq head
          (cons
           (cons
            (format
             (format "%%-%ds  %%s%%s" maxlen)
             (buffer-name elt)
             (if (buffer-modified-p elt) "*" " ")
             (with-current-buffer elt
               (if buffer-read-only "%" " "))
                     )
            elt)
           head))))
      (setq tail (cdr tail)))
    ;; Compensate for the reversal that the above loop does.
    (nreverse head)))
```

Comment: PS: This function is taken from the Emacs23 source. For Emacs24 it might look a bit different.

Comment: Thanks for steering me in the right direction. Incidentally, if you don't like having subgroups in the menu (this was my case, because I don't like selecting a buffer to be a two-step process), you can set the mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult variable to a large number in .emacs init file. See comments in mouse.el source file.